# verilog_mode autoreginput behavior when using assignment

Tags: emacs, verilog, system-verilog

I wonder if the following case is possible.
I have :

```
module a(
input [2:0] a_i
);
endmodule

module b ();

 /*AUTOREGINPUTS*/

 a u_a(/*AUTOINST*/)
endmodule
```

It expands to:

```
 module b ();

 /*AUTOREGINPUTS*/
 reg [2:0] a_i;
 a u_a(/*AUTOINST*/
       .a_i(a_i))
endmodule
```

But if I modify adding the line `assign a_i  = '0;`, then it does not expands `AUTOREGINPUTS` anymore. Is there a way to expand it even if I'm doing an assignment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is because when running `verilog-auto` to fill in `/*AUTOREGINPUT*/` will exclude any signal that is already declared and by adding `assign a_i = '0;`, you are declaring `a_i`.

In Verilog, explicit variable declarations are not required and will take on the default nettype if left undeclared under certain circumstances. So, if I had the following:

```
module x;
  assign myVar = '0;
endmodule
```

`myVar` will be implicitly declared to be a net with the default nettype (which by default is `wire`). You can read more in the System-Verilog LRM (IEEE1800-2009 Section 6.10). One recommendation to avoid typos generating implicitly declared variables is to change the default nettype with the `` `default_nettype `` macro to `none` (ie `` `default_nettype none `` on the top of every file); doing this forces all variables to be explicitly declared or the compiler/synthesizer will throw an error.

`verilog-mode` mode in emacs is aware of implicit declaration and, as such, will not autogenerate anything declared. Thus, when you add the `assign` statement, you are declaring `a_i` and so the autogenerator will not "redefine" `a_i`.

To avoid this, I can only recommend running the generator before you assign any of the variables to be autogenerated. Im not sure if it handles `` `default_nettype none `` correctly, but I would assume not.

Also note, it should be `/*AUTOREGINPUT*/`, not `/*AUTOREGINPUTS*/`, no 's' at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
Then I'll do as you say, remove the assigns, expand autos and copy the the declared logic